# Laravel : Call to undefined method setasign\Fpdi\Fpdi::GetPageWidth() using Fpdi

Tags: laravel, fpdf, fpdi

I have a template located at "`public/form/file.pdf`" and what to get the page height and the page width but I'm encountering error *"Call to undefined method setasign\Fpdi\Fpdi::GetPageWidth()"*

I installed via composer of the following packages:

```
"setasign/fpdf": "1.8",
"setasign/fpdi": "^2.3"
```

**Controller**

```
$pdf = new Fpdi();
$page_count = $pdf->setSourceFile(public_path()."/form/file.pdf");
$w = $pdf->GetPageWidth();  // Width of Current Page
$h = $pdf->GetPageHeight(); // Height of Current Page
dd($w);
```

Question: How do I get the width and height of current page?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you receive this error? I mean the called methods are standard methods of [FPDF](https://github.com/Setasign/FPDF/blob/master/fpdf.php#L929). You can get the size of an imported page like this:

```
$tplId = $pdf->importPage(1);
$size = $pdf->getImportedPageSize($tplId);

echo $size['width'];
echo $size['height'];
echo $size['orientation'];
```

For details see [here](https://manuals.setasign.com/fpdi-manual/v2/the-fpdi-class/#c_setasignFpdiFpdiTraitgetImportedPageSize).

Answer (score 0):

You must create a page before you can access it's dimensions.

```
$pdf = new Fpdi();
$pdf->setSourceFile($file);

$templateId = $pdf->importPage(1);
$size = $pdf->getTemplateSize($templateId);

$pdf->AddPage($size['orientation'], $size);
$pdf->useTemplate($templateId);

$w = $pdf->GetPageWidth();
$h = $pdf->GetPageHeight();
```

See the following example from the documentation as reference: https://manuals.setasign.com/fpdi-manual/v2/the-fpdi-class/examples/#index-3